# How to evaluate this infinite sum involving powers and trigonometric terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I wish to find out the following infinite sum:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^k\sin\left[\frac{2\pi}{3(2^k)}\right]$$

I can sum up a GP or an AGP well, and know telescoping series, how can I find this infinite sum? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any reason to think the sum can be expressed in closed form?

Comment: What is the origin of the problem?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I didnt get you....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a closed form. When $k$ is sufficiently large, the argument of the sine becomes tiny and you can use a linear approximation. Hence, denoting $S$ the infinite sum (which converges),

$$\sum_{k=0}^na^k\sin(2^{-k}b)\approx S_{a,b}-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a^k2^{-k}b=S_{a,b}-\frac{a^{n+1}b}{2^{n}(2-a)}.$$

A better approximation is obtained by using the next term in the Taylor developments, giving 
$$\sum_{k=0}^na^k\sin(2^{-k}b)\approx S_{a,b}-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a^k2^{-k}b+\frac16\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a^k(2^{-k}b)^3
\\=S_{a,b}-\frac{a^{n+1}b}{2^{n}(2-a)}+\frac{a^{n+1}b^3}{6\cdot8^{n}(8-a)},$$

and so on.

Comment: Why not use the whole Taylor series?  For $|a| <2$, 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n \sin(2^{-n} b) = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }-2\,{\frac {{4}^{k} \left( -1 \right) ^{k}{b}^{2
\,k+1}}{ \left(a -2\cdot {4}^{k} \right)  \left( 2\,k+1 \right) !}}
$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael: this was implied by "and so on". ;-)